# Setting up an Alarm system on android

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, alarm, repeatingalarm

Im developing an app with a feature by which people can set reminders for themselves for various events (like take medicine with dosage amount). The user should be able to

1) Set a time for the reminder

2) Set a date for the reminder and choose between recurring/ non-recurring

3) When the alarm gets triggered, a notification should be built for the user

4) Alarm should have a snooze option as well

I know how to use notification builder to add a notification with a pending intent and have read documentation on Alarm Manager but Im still completely lost with this task. Could someone please give me some guidance or help?

Comment: Sometimes ago I was writing something like this and one of the caveats that I had to face was that sometimes my alarms get lost.

You have to store the alarms somewhere (like database) so that you can reset them when needed.

see here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041208/how-to-reset-alarm-if-app-is-force-closed-in-android

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the following will supply sufficient documentation on interfacing with alarms in the android SDK.

> https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html